# Documentation for Robotium test cases,Android

Tags: android, robotium

From long time i am searching for some documentation for Robotium test cases.
So please tell me from where i will get the same.

Answer (score 2):

Soon we will upload some tutorials about Robotium. For know you can get some idea from

http://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/RobotiumTutorials

if you have not visited this page so far. If you are facing some specific issue, you can also ping us.

Answer (score 1):

Javadoc is distributed in jar form at https://code.google.com/p/robotium/downloads/list.

However, that's really annoying and lame. It's just HTML, so why not post it on the web somewhere??

UPDATE: Seems that this has been done: http://robotium.googlecode.com/svn/doc/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can download the javadoc for Robotium here: http://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/QuestionsAndAnswers

This should give you all you need.